# Run extension on page refresh?

Tags: extension, plugin

I am new to plugin/extension development in EE. I currently have an extension that creates a cookie and saves a value to it. What I want is on every page refresh this value to be updated.

Is there a way to have the extension run on each page refresh?

Answer (score 4):

Yes: use the [sessions_end hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/session/index.html). It runs on every page load. Be sure to check to see if you're using it on the front-end before you set your cookie (I assume you want this for the front-end only).

```
if(REQ != 'CP')
{
    // do your stuff
}
```